# Colocar uma div do lado da outra

Tags: css

Gente estou com um probleminha no css, queria que uma div ficasse uma do lado da outra. Já tentei colocar float nas duas, mas se faço isso a div rodapé sobe. O que eu faço?

```
#DivRodape{
position: absolute;
top: auto;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
background-color:#004085;
}


#DivLateral{
position:relative;
border-width:2px;
width:300px;
height: 700px;
background-color: peachpuff;
}

#DivA{
position: relative;
border-width:2px;
width:auto;
height: auto;
left:300px;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@J.Jones vc tem que usar o `clear:both` no grupo para quebrar a **flutuação** quando se usa `Float` no elementos. Para resolver o seu problema criei uma `Div` por fora chamada .grupo e nela eu criei um pseudoelement `::after` e usei o estilo `clear:both` para limpar a flutuação e jogar o `rodape` pra baixo. Da uma olhada no código que vc vai entender.

***OBS*** fiz uma mudanças no seu CSS apenas para vc visualizar melhor o que foi feito.

Clique em **EXECUTAR** para ver o código funcionando

```css
#DivRodape{
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#004085;
}
#DivLateral{
    position:relative;
    border-width:2px;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: peachpuff;
    float: left;
}
#DivA{
    position: relative;
    border-width:2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
     zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <div id="DivA"></div>
    <div id="DivLateral"></div>
</div>
<div id="DivRodape"></div>
```

> Pesquise sobre "Clear Fix CSS" e vc vai ver vários exemplos.

Aqui tem uma fonte de referência em português
https://edsonjunior.com/entendendo-float-clear-clearfix/

Answer (score 0):

Tens que colocar float: left nas duas divs.

```
#DivLateral{
position:relative;
float: left;
border-width:2px;
width:300px;
height: 700px;
background-color: peachpuff;
}

#DivA{
position: relative;
float: left;
border-width:2px;
width:auto;
height: auto;
left:300px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize
`display: inline-block;`

Vai colocar um do lado outro, criará uma margin, isso você pode corrigir com margin negativa.
Exemplo:
`Margin: -5px;`

Answer (score -3):

#div1 {

```
width: 950px;

height: 1500px;

background: #b8a88e;

margin: 5% 8%;
```

}

#div2 {

```
width: 200px;

height: 1000px;

background:#f8f8f8;

margin: 8% 3%;

position: absolute;

top: 0px;

right: 0px;
```